# How to jump to a specific page in a multipage Webform?

Tags: webforms, forms, navigation

I have a multipage [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform), and I'm using [Webform Bonus Pack](http://drupal.org/project/webform_bonus) to display a summary at the end before the user finally submits the form.

What I'd like to do is provide "edit" links alongside the various sections of the form data so the user can jump to the page containing those fields.

Does anyone know how I can do this or, failing that, can anyone at least throw me a bone and tell me how Webform decides which page to display after a "next/previous" button is pressed on a multipage form?

I thought I'd be cute and use Javascript to change the value of the hidden "details[page_num]" field to be one greater than the target page, then invoke a `click()` on the Previous button, but to no avail; it still goes back to the previous (second to last) page. There is a `$_POST['details']['page_num']` containing the current page number, but it's apparently not used to determine where the Next and Previous buttons take the form.

Answer (score 2):

I've just published a [webform_steps](http://drupal.org/project/webform_steps) module that provides a navigation bar for multi page webforms. It solves the problem by implementing a submit-handler that simulates the next and previous buttons very similar to how you describe it.

The magic has to happen on the PHP side in the `$form_state` array.