# Dynamic webforms workflow

Tags: webforms, workflows, forms

I know how to setup a multi-page webforms (basically add page breaks' between each page).  I also know how to use the conditionals to skip certain questions based on the values or state of previous questions.

However, I would like to do this dynamically.  So instead of using conditionals to change the workflow, I would like to use my own logic (code) to decide what the next question should be.  The reason is I have a webforms with 42 questions (pages) and the actual workflow can change significantly.

All I am really asking is how do I tell webforms what the next question is that should be shown.

I guess it is similar to this question ([How to jump to a specific page in a multipage Webform](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/63168/how-to-jump-to-a-specific-page-in-a-multipage-webform)) but the solution quoted ([Webform steps Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_steps)) does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I added hook_form_alter and checked if I am working with webforms (I suppose you can check if you are working with a specific webform), and then added a custom validation call-back:

```
  if (strstr($form_id, 'webform_client_form') !== FALSE) {
    if (empty ($form['#validate']['_set_next_page'])) {
      $form['#validate'][] = '_set_next_page';
    }
  }
```

In the _set_next_page function I get the value of the submitted component.  In my case there is only one question per page, but you can easily adapt that

```
$submitted = array_keys($form_state['values']['submitted']);
```

Remember if this is the first page (question), the array looks slightly different, so:

```
  if ($form_state['webform']['page_num'] == 1) {
    $Q = $submitted[0];
  }
  else {
    $Q = $submitted[1];
  }
  // Get the value that was submitted
  $value = $form_state['values']['submitted'][$Q];
```

Assuming $destination holds the 'form_key' of the question you want to jump too:

```
   if ($destination) {
    foreach ($node->webform['components'] as $component) {
      if ($component['form_key'] == $destination) {
        $nextPage = $component['page_num'] - 1;
        if (($nextPage > 1)
          && ($nextPage < $form_state['webform']['page_count'])) 
        {
          $form_state['webform']['page_num'] = $nextPage;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I set the page_num to the page_number for the destination component to one less, because webforms will increment this value once the submission is processed.

I am sure the code needs some re-finement (make sure that I do not crash and burn while accessing array elements / objects that does not exist) - but you get the idea.

Hope this helps someone else.